# error when trying to write in the turtle window

Tags: python

I get this error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\_Muh Stuff\IT\Learning\Python\Projet Hanoi\Main_Program.py", line 106, in <module>
    tab_res()
  File "c:\_Muh Stuff\IT\Learning\Python\Projet Hanoi\Partie_E.py", line 81, in tab_res
    write(elem, ": ", all_keys[i], "\n")
  File "<string>", line 8, in write
  File "C:\Users\Augustin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\turtle.py", line 3431, in write
    end = self._write(str(arg), align.lower(), font)
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

From this code:

```
`for i in range(0, len(all_keys)):
    if i == 6:
        break

    elem = dict1[all_keys[i]]

    print(elem, ": ", all_keys[i])

    turtle.write(elem, ": ", all_keys[i], "\n")

    del dict1[all_keys[i]]`
```

I just don't understand how this error is linked to turtle

Could it be because of the "\n" at the end??

Comment: Show us the definition of `write()`.  That's not a standard python function.

Comment: please provide a proper [mcve]

Comment: i edited it a bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`write()` is not like `print()`.

`print()` will take as many arguments as you want to give it, and each will be printed as part of the resulting string, automatically separated by spaces.

The signature of the `write()` method, on the other hand, is as follows:

```
 def write(self, arg, move=False, align="left", font=("Arial", 8, "normal")):
```

(source: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/turtle.py ). It takes a single string as its first argument, and the subsequent positional arguments have different purposes. Typically we will call it with just one argument, a string that we want to write.

I made up some test data to make your code work, and rigged it up to do what you want.

```
import turtle

my_turtle = turtle.Turtle()

# This fake dictionary contains some testing data.
# Everything is assumed to be a string.
dict1 = {"2": "Test",
         "random": "ASDF",
         ":-)": "qwerty",
         "8": "Cheese"}

# This is the order in which the lines will be processed
all_keys = ["8", "2", ":-)", "random"]

for i in range(0, len(all_keys)):
    if i == 6:
        break
    elem = dict1[all_keys[i]]

    # We will use this output string in both the print() and write() methods.
    output = elem + ": " + all_keys[i]

    print(output)
    my_turtle.write(output)

    # This will have the effect of moving the pen a little further down the screen,
    # to act a bit like "\n".
    my_turtle.penup()
    my_turtle.right(90)
    my_turtle.forward(20)
    my_turtle.left(90)
    my_turtle.pendown()

    del dict1[all_keys[i]]

my_turtle.done()
```

Note that `\n` is only valid within each string we `write` and has no effect on subsequent strings. So they will all be written over the top of each other by default.

In my example I fake it by manually moving the turtle to the start of the next line. Another alternative would be build up a large output string containing each line separated by `\n` characters and write this all at once (which will work).